# Dynamic, individual nodeAffinity for each pod in a StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes

I have two node pools: `NP1` and `NP2`.
I have a `StatefulSet` with pods using ordinal index to retrieve their own configuration from external configuration source.

On certain conditions, I need to reschedule individual pods to either `NP1` or `NP2`. Actual information about which pod should be run on which node pool is stored in a Consul KV object.

I can write a Kubernetes Operator which subscribes on that object and modifies `StatefulSet` in a way that it reschedules individual pods to a correct node pool when Consul KV object is updated. My question is how can I define different `nodeAffinity` for each pod?

I've seen some examples of using `topologyKey` with `podAntiAffinity` but in my case the decision which node pool a pod should be scheduled on is based on data completely external from kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure only a Mutating Webhook will allow you to do dynamic tricks like that; I think OPA has some concessions toward that use case, but I've thankfully never used it

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use [mutating webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) as [mdaniel](https://serverfault.com/users/330715/mdaniel) has mentioned in the comment:

> I'm pretty sure only a Mutating Webhook will allow you to do dynamic tricks like that; I think OPA has some concessions toward that use case.

You can also find here more information about [Dynamic Admission Control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/).